# Can anyone find any bugs or mistakes in this code?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have been working on this code for hours, and I still can solve it.
 inside the function build a forever loop (infinite while loop) and inside the loop complete the following

I want it to use a variable to gather input which is supposed to be either an integer of 'q' to quit.
It should check if the input string is a digit (integer) and if it is...
add input integer to report variable.
If the variable  is "A" add the numeric character(s) to the item string seperated by a new line.
If the report type is q, 
If the report type is "A" print out all the integer items entered and the sum total.
If report type is "T" then print out the sum total only
break out of while loop to end the function after printing the report ("A" or "T").
If not a digit and if not a "Q" then print a message that the "input is invalid".

```
def adding_report(report=[]):
report = []
at = input("Choose a report type: 'A' or 'T' : ")
while at.lower() != 'a' and at.lower() != 't':
    print('what?')
    at = input("Choose a report type: 'A' or 'T' : ")
while True:
    re = input("print an integer or 'Q' : ")
    if re.isdigit() is True:
        report.append(re)
        report.append('\n')
    elif re.startswith('q') is True:
        if at.lower() == 'a' is True:
            break
            print(report)
            print(sum(report))
        elif at.lower() == 't' is True:
            print(sum(report))
            break
        else:
            pass
    elif re.isallnum() is False and re.lower().startswith('q') is False:
        print('invalid response.')
    else:
        pass
adding_report(report=[])
```

If anyone found any way to fix the bugs, could they please tell me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Indenting matters in Python. The code you posted is not indented properly — is this the way you have it in your code? If not, you should edit the sample you posted to accurately reflect your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must put tabulation to code at least here

```
def adding_report(report=[]): # <-- You have errors here, defined function has nothing in it
report = [] # <-- I suggest tabulating this
```

this is incorrect usage, and it works

```
if re.isdigit() is True: # Not recommended
```

whenever you check **if something is True**, just **Do not do it**,

this is better way for simple if statement:

```
if re.isdigit(): # Recommended, will excecute when it returns any value, except (False and None)
```

move break after code, if you want it to excecute:

```
  break # <-- this stops loop! you won't print anything that is after it
  print(report)
  print(sum(report))
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to do something like this maybe? I've changed a bit your code and made some comments where the errors where present.

```
def adding_report(report=[]):
    report = []
    at = input("Choose a report type: 'A' or 'T' : ")
    while at.lower() != 'a' and at.lower() != 't':
        print('what?')
        at = input("Choose a report type: 'A' or 'T' : ")
    while True:
        re = input("print an integer or 'Q' : ")
        print(re)
        if re.isdigit(): # Remove is true
            report.append(int(re)) # Add integer to list. Use int() to convert string to int

        elif re.startswith('q'): # Remove is true
            if at.lower() == 'a':
                print(report) # This two prints MUST be above de break statement in ordered to be executed
                print(sum(report))
                break
            elif at.lower() == 't': # Remove is true
                print(sum(report))
                break
            else:
                pass

        elif not re.isdigit() and not re.lower().startswith('q'): # Replaced is False with not
            print('invalid response.')
        else:
            pass
adding_report(report=[])
```

Comment: I still am getting the error unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'. Also, my code was supposed to print all the integers seperated by a new line. Sorry that you couldn't see this in my first post.

Comment: On which line are you getting that error? I've tested the code above and works fine. Keep in mind that you have to convert the numbers inputted by console to integers by using int() function. Moreover, in order to print the integers separated by a new line you can loop over the report list and print each one, for example:
for number in report:
    print(number)

Comment: Thanks. Also, I am getting that error on line 16 and 18.